# Find perpendicular line using points on that line

Tags: math, coordinates, line

I have a line (P1, P2), and a point on that line (midpoint). What equation can I used to find the perpendicular line of line (P1, P2), that passes through midpoint. The point labelled with a '?' is unknown. I do not wish to use angles, only the 3 points given (P1, P2, midpoint). The line P1, P2 can be of any orientation/angle.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mathematics, not programming.

Comment: What programming language do you want to use to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Let define vector

```
D = P2 - P1  (dx=x2-x1, dy = y2-y1)
```

and middle point

```
mx = (x2+x1)/2
my = (y2+y1)/2
```

Perpendicular to D vector

```
PD = (-dy, dx)
```

Unit (normalized) perpendicular vector

```
U = (-dy / L, dx / L)
where
L = Sqrt (dx * dx + dy * dy)
```

And coordinates of point lying at distance F from the middle are

```
x = mx + U.x * F
y = my + U.y * F
```

or (for point at another side)

```
x = mx - U.x * F
y = my - U.y * F
```

Comment: This is definitely correct. Perhaps there are some mistakes in implementation....

Comment: my fault. I had a small issue with my code.. now the question is what needs to be done if I wanted to perform the same thing if we add z-axis value to it.

Comment: In 3D case we have infinite number of perpendiculars (circle circumference), so it is necessary to select some direction - depends on the real task.

Comment: I know the length of the perpendicular line and I know the mid-point and I have both vertices P1, P2 in x,y,z coordinates. How can I get the coordinates of that vertex that performs the perpendicular line that I'm trying to draw. Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: How do you want to choose some direction from infinite number of possible directions? Randomly? Some preference?

Comment: I'll write a question with an example and will paste it here once I'm done.

Comment: I've been looking for this calc for a while, but I need it in 3D. How is this looking in 3D space?

Comment: @arnoldino There is infinite number of perpendiculars in 3d without additional conditions.  [Get arbitrary perpendicular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340313/finding-point-of-t-distance-on-a-perpendicular-line-on-the-same-plane-as-a-given/22343809#22343809)

Answer (score 0):

Coordinates of P1: (x1,y1)
Coordinates of P2: (x2,y2)

Coordinates of midpoint: ( (x1+x2)/2 , (y1+y2)/2)
Slope of the P1P2 line: (y1-y2)/(x1-x2)
Slope of any perpendicular line to P1P2: (x2-x1)/(y1-y2)

Equation of the red line: y - (y1+y2)/2 = ((x2-x1)/(y1-y2))*(x - (x1+x2)/2)

If you have the actual values of coordinates of P1 y P2, then just make a substitution.

Comment: thank you for the reply, however I do not fully understand how to calculate the coordinate of '?'?

Comment: You would need to know, first of all, the distance between the black line and the '?' spot.

Comment: @Daniel Saldaña Avoid using slopes in computational geometry, they don't exist for vertical and/or horizontal lines

Comment: You are right @MBo, but I used them because Joe Morgan said: "The line P1, P2 can be of any orientation/angle."